# Solving a linear first-order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am looking to solve a linear first-order PDE of the form

$$(e^{\beta x} - \alpha x -1 ) f_x(x,t) - f_t(x,t) + \gamma x f(x,t) =0$$

with boundary conditions $f(0,t)=1$ and $f(x,0)=e^{x\lambda}$.

I tried the methods of characteristics, but did not get any meaningful conclusion. Does this one has an explicit solution? And if yes, how can I get it constructively?

Comment: What is $f_s(x, t)$? Did you mean $f_x(x, t)$?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean. I corrected the text.

Comment: I don't believe that the characteristic equation for $x$ has an explicit closed form

Comment: What's the origin of this PDE? Homework? Research?

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha finds an explicit solution for the PDE (without boundary conditions) as you can see here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DSolve%5B%28E%5E%28%5C%5BBeta%5D+x%29+-+%5C%5BAlpha%5D+x+-+1%29+Derivative%5B1%2C+0%5D%5Bf%5D%5Bx%2C+t%5D+-+Derivative%5B0%2C+1%5D%5Bf%5D%5Bx%2C+t%5D+%2B+%5C%5BGamma%5D+x+f%5Bx%2C+t%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C%7Bf%5Bx%2Ct%5D%2Cf%5Bx%2Ct%5D%7D%2C%7Bt%2Cx%7D%5D) This may help...

Answer (score 1):

$$(e^{\beta x} - \alpha x -1 ) f_x(x,t) - f_t(x,t) =- \gamma x f(x,t) $$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{e^{\beta x} - \alpha x -1}=\frac{dt}{-1}=\frac{df}{-\gamma x\:f }$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{e^{\beta x} - \alpha x -1}=\frac{dt}{-1}$ :
$$t+\int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{e^{\beta x} - \alpha x -1}=\frac{f}{-\gamma x }$ :
$$f+\int_0^x \frac{\gamma\: \xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ leads to :
$$\boxed{f(x,t)=-\gamma \int_0^x \frac{\xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}+F\left(t+\int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}\right)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

BOUNDARY CONDITION : $f(0,t)=1$

$f(0,t)=1=-\gamma \int_0^0 \frac{\xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}+F\left(t+\int_0^0 \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}\right)=F(t)$

The function $F$ is determined as a constant : $F=1$. We put it into the above general solution.
$$f_1(x,t)=1-\gamma \int_0^x \frac{\xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1} \tag1$$

INITIAL CONDITION : $f(x,0)=e^{x\lambda}$

$$e^{\lambda x}=-\gamma \int_0^x \frac{\xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}+\Phi\left(0+\int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}\right)$$
The notation $F$ is changed to $\Phi$ to make clear that this is not the same function than above for the boundary condition.
$$\Phi\left(\int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}\right)=e^{\lambda x}+\gamma \int_0^x \frac{\xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}$$

$$\text{Let}\quad X(x)=\int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}\quad \text{and let}\quad x(X)\quad \text{the inverse function.}$$
$$\Phi\left(X\right)=e^{\lambda x(X)}+\gamma \int_0^{x(X)} \frac{\xi\:d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}$$
This determines the function $\Phi$. One put it into the above general solution where the argument is $\left(t+\int_0^x \frac{d\xi}{e^{\beta \xi} - \alpha \xi -1}\right)$. This gives a second solution $f_2(x,t)$.

Of course this is purely theoretical. One cannot find a closed form for the integral and even more one cannot find a closed form for the inverse function $x(X)$.

So the conclusion is that the solution of the problem probably cannot be expressed on a closed form. The problem will require numerical methods of solving.

Note : Two solutions $f_1(x,t)$ and $f_2(x,t)$ wre mentioned. Of course they are not both valid together everywhere. The solution is a picewise function made of $f_1(x,t)$ and $f_2(x,t)$ each one valid in a limited region limited by the respective conditions.